# How to share flutter Linux desktop release application without uploading to Snap Store

Tags: flutter, flutter-linux

I created a flutter Linux release application and I want to test that application on different Linux systems. How I can share my Linux Application with other users.

Comment: Hi, did you find the answer?

Comment: @YakhyoMashrapov Not yet

Comment: Recently I found that if you compress and share bundle folder inside release folder, you can open it on other machines

Comment: @YakhyoMashrapov cool can you please share the link where did you find that solution.

Comment: I found it experimentally) 
Just run "flutter build linux"
Go to your project folder, then build/linux/x64/release/bundle
Open file named as your project

Answer (score 1):

You can run at the root directory of your project the command `flutter build linux --release`.

Then in the `build/linux/x64/release/bundle` folder of you project you can find an executable file with your app's name. You can change directory to the location of this file and run it via `./your_file_name`